# Skill Development Notitification

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-sns

we have build product in which you can create deploy alexa skill easily without any development experience. we are using SMAPI and aws SDK to create skill, publish interaction model and manifest, submit skill for certification and all other stuff..

I wanted to use alexa skill development notification
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/sdns/use-skill-development-notifications.html
so I can listen to all the skill related event in my SNS
I followed steps mentioned in the above doc but in the first step while creating subscriber I am getting

```
{
    "message": "You do not have access to the resource."
}
```

so here are the steps that followed
Generate lwa token using ask cli (scopes = ) ask util generate-lwa-tokens --scopes "alexa::ask:subscriptions" --client-id XXXX --client-confirmation XX
use that token to call below API
https://api.amazonalexa.com/v0/developmentEvents/subscribers/

```
  "name": "Example Development Event Subscriber",
  "endpoint": {
        "uri": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:XXX:SkillDevelopmentNotification.fifo",
        "authorization": {
            "type": "AWS_IAM",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/SkillDevelopmentNotificationIAMRole"
        }
    },
  "vendorId": "XXX"
}
```

I checked the IAM role i think its properly configured.. but can you help me with this ?

Comment: I'd like to make sure if you added external ID with your Vendor ID. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/sdns/use-skill-development-notifications.html#create-iam-role